# AEM Servlet ResourceType in AJAX URL

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, aem

Hello I want to use the sling ResourceType as oppose to the servletpath.

So this is my original path:

```
@Component(service=Servlet.class,
property={"sling.servlet.paths=/bin/jit/ccpa",
          "sling.servlet.extensions=html",
          "sling.servlet.methods=" + METHOD_POST}
)
```

And this is an update for the resourceType.

```
@Component(service=Servlet.class,
property={"sling.servlet.resourceTypes="+"falcon/components/pages/rwd/page_home",
          "sling.servlet.extensions=html",
          "sling.servlet.selectors="+"sample",
          "sling.servlet.methods=" + METHOD_POST}
)
```

For my ajax call how should I configure it?

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/bin/jit/ccpa',
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != "" && data != "error") {
                        var res = $.parseJSON(data);
                        if (res === undefined || res === null || res.sendEmailResponse === undefined) {
                            formError(form, container);
                        }
                    }
                error: function () {
                    formError(form, container);
                }
            });
```

What goes in the URL value in the Ajax call?
And is my resourceType value correct in my Servlet, how is that usually obtained?

Answer (score 1):

You can expose that information in Sling model of that component.
Then in htl JS can get that information and use it for ajax calls.

So create getter which returns path of that resource + additionally selectors/extension based how you define your servlet.

```
this.request.getResource().getPath() + ".sample.html";
//or
this.resource.getPath() + ".sample.html";
```

Answer (score 0):

A servlet listening on a resource type means it will activate whenever a resource of this type is requested. This means I can’t tell you whether the resource type you used is correct nor what the URL would be because it depends on the contents of your repository.

With your suggested changes, you could create a node of type `nt:unstructured` with the `sling:resourceType` property set to `falcon/components/pages/rwd/page_home`. If your node resides at `/content/your-site/some/path/ccpa`, a POST request to `/content/your-site/some/path/ccpa.html` will hit the servlet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the servlet from ajax, you need to register a servlet by path only. When you register using resourceType, then the servlet is called only when the component present in the resourceType is invoked or loaded.